# Resource Package Pathway in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, package, imageicon

In short, I am not fully sure where the following syntax leaves me, in regards to pathing to my images. I want "treetop.png" to be loaded, but I keep getting nullpointer errors.

```
ImageIcon treetop1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/treetop.png"));
```

I looked up somewhere that this leads to the /res folder by default (not even sure if that's true), so anything under the package "resources" should be the starting point of this, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Here is my folder setup, I would preferably like to store all my images under the "images" package, but I have no idea how to path this.

[image]

*The project is "FunGame", so that is the top of the hierarchy.

Thank you!

Comment: Try using `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/treetop.png")`

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work! (I think, I got errors due to some static problems, but it compiled past the imageicon code at least).